# Display random image with fitting link

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm using the below code to show random images which works fine. How can I add to this code so that each image gets it's own link? I.e. if "knife.png" is randomly picked I want it to have a link that takes the user to "products/knife.html" and so on.

Thanks for any help!

```
<div id="box">
<img id="image" /></div>

<script type='text/javascript'> 

var images = [
"images/knife.png",
"images/fork.png",
"images/spoon.png",
"images/chopsticks.png",];

function randImg() {
var size = images.length
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
document.getElementById('image').src = images[x];
}

randImg();
```

Comment: Put an <a> tag around the image and use the same technique to change its href attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalize your list of images so that that it can be multi-purposed - you can add additional information later. Then surround the image by an anchor tag (`<a>`) and use the following.

```
<div id="box">
  <a name="imagelink"><img id="image" /></a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
  var images = ["knife","fork","spoon","chopsticks",];

  function randImg() {
    var size = images.length
    var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
    document.getElementById('image').src = "images/"+images[x]+".png";
    document.getElementById('imagelink').href="products/"+images[x]+".html";
  }
</script>

randImg();
```

Comment: Hmm, this appears to not work for me. Instead of a valid link clicking the picture simply reloads the current page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, I changed 
    <a href="" name="imagelink"><img id="image" /></a>
into
    <a id="imagelink"><img id="image" /></a></div>
and now it seems to work. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cVnTn/). Like all these other guys have said, it's better to store this info in a database or something, but to answer your question, put the values you need into an object in the array and reference the properties of the object instead of just having a string array.

```
<div id="box">
    <a id="a"><img id="image" /></a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
var images = 
[
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"http://www.dansdata.com/images/bigknife/bigknife1280.jpg", Href:"http://reluctantgourmet.com/tools/cutlery/item/267-chefs-knife-choosing-the-right-cutlery" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"http://www.hometownsevier.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/fork.jpg", Href:"http://eofdreams.com/fork.html" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/Soup_Spoon.jpg", Href:"http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Soup_Spoon.jpg" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Ouashi.jpg", Href:"http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Chopsticks" },
]

function randImg() {
var size = images.length;
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random());
var randomItem = images[x];
document.getElementById('image').src = randomItem.ImgSrc;
document.getElementById('a').href = randomItem.Href;
}

randImg();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `img` with an `a`

```
<a href="#" id="link"><img id="image" /></a>
```

Then add

```
document.getElementById("link").href = images[x].replace(".png",".html");
```

The `.replace` is a bit crude, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a convention based approach.  In this case the convention is that each product, will have an associated image at "/image/[product]/.png" and a page at "products/[product].html"

```
<div id="box">
<a id="link"><img id="image" /></a></div>

<script type='text/javascript'> 

var products = [
"knife",
"fork",
"spoon",
"chopsticks",];

function randImg() {
var size = images.length
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
document.getElementById('image').src = "/images/" + products[x] + ".png";
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute("href", "products/" + products[x] + ".html");
}

randImg();
```

this is a very naive approach that won't scale very well.  for example, if you have a list of products that changes frequently, or, you need to keep track of the number of available units.  a more robust approach would be to store information about your products in a database, and a page that displays the data about a given product (a product detail page), and then use a data access technology to fetch a list of products for display in a product list page (similar to what you have here, except the list of products isn't hardcoded) and then each product would link to the product detail page.